# type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi in the below code when I am hit the signin button showing below error ,below details are passing as body I am able to print the data but response is not coming anything.

Enter mobile number and password able to see the response in postman but from app not getting any error.

Can any one help me where I did the mistake

```
{Mobile: 8250030771, Password: Test@123, Otp: N, Type: Patient}
Error: type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression
```

SignIn.dart:

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 late String mobile, password,otp,type;
  bool isLoading=false;
  TextEditingController _mobileController=new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController=new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _otpController=new TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>_scaffoldKey=GlobalKey();
  late ScaffoldMessengerState scaffoldMessenger ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/background.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                      child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/logo.png",
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 13,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Learn With Us",
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 27,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 1)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 180,
                    child: Text(
                      "RRTutors, Hyderabad",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white54,
                            letterSpacing: 0.6,
                            fontSize: 11),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Sign In",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: 1,
                        fontSize: 23,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Learn new Technologies ",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            letterSpacing: 1,
                            fontSize: 17,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Container(
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 45),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            controller: _mobileController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                              hintText: "Mobile",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                            onSaved: (val) {
                              mobile = val!;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 16,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                              hintText: "Password",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                            onSaved: (val) {
                              mobile = val!;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  if(isLoading)
                                    {
                                      return;
                                    }
                                  if(_mobileController.text.isEmpty||_passwordController.text.isEmpty)
                                  {
                                    scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("Please Fill all fileds")));
                                    return;
                                  }
                                  login(_mobileController.text,_passwordController.text,);
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading=true;
                                  });
                                  //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10, horizontal: 0),
                                  height: 50,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "SUBMIT",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            letterSpacing: 1)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(child: (isLoading)?Center(child: Container(height:26,width: 26,child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.green,))):Container(),right: 30,bottom: 0,top: 0,)

                            ],
                          )

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "OR",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white60),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/fingerprint.png",
                    height: 36,
                    width: 36,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/signup");
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Don't have an account?",
                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white70,
                              fontSize: 13,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              letterSpacing: 0.5)),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  login(mobile,password) async
  {
    Map data = {
      'Mobile': mobile,
      'Password': password,
      'Otp':"N",
      'Type':"Patient",
    };
    print(data.toString());
    final  response= await http.post(
        Uri.parse(LOGIN),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },


        body: data,
        encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
    )  ;
    setState(() {
      isLoading=false;
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String,dynamic> resposne=jsonDecode(response.body);
      if(!resposne['error'])
      {
        Map<String,dynamic>user=resposne['data'];
        print(" LoginId ${user['LoginId']}");
        savePref(1,user['name'],user['email'],user['id']);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
      }else{
        print(" ${resposne['Message']}");
      }
      scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("${resposne['Message']}")));

    } else {
      scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("Please try again!")));
    }


  }
  savePref(int value, String name, String email, int id) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      preferences.setInt("value", value);
      preferences.setString("name", name);
      preferences.setString("email", email);
      preferences.setString("id", id.toString());
      preferences.commit();

  }
}
```

Comment: Check all your if statements if the value is really a boolean. Maybe you get a Null back from e.g. if(!resposne['error']). To fix this, add a null check there.

Answer (score 0):

boolean expression is only contains `true` or `false`,

your data can be `null` then you can make `if` statement

```
    bool data(data){
    if(data==null){
     return false;
     }
    else{
     return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your provided information didn't enough to solve the issue but I guess the issue is caused here:

```dart
 Map<String,dynamic> resposne=jsonDecode(response.body);
      if(!resposne['error']) // <---------- HERE
      {
        Map<String,dynamic>user=resposne['data'];
        print(" LoginId ${user['LoginId']}");
        savePref(1,user['name'],user['email'],user['id']);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
      }else{
        print(" ${resposne['Message']}");
      }
```

Because the `response` doesn't contain `'error'` parameter so the result will be `Null` and you can't use `!` with `null` value, so you can check if it's `null` or not before using `!` like below:

```dart
if (response['error'] != null && !resposne['error']) {
```

You can try the answer and let me know if it works or not and give me the `response` result to make sure where the issue is and I will edit this answer to solve the issue.